# Device div screens overlapping, how do I fix?

Tags: css, html

How do i change the keyboard functions to an onscreen joystick?
I am building a html5 game and Im completely lost as the how to add a joystick.

Below is the code that needs some help. Thank you very much in advance :)

```
function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  enemy = new Image();
  enemy.src = '8bit_enemy.png';
  ship = new Image();
  ship.src = 'ship.png';
  starfield = new Image();
  starfield.src = 'starfield.jpg';
  document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown, false);
  document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('click', gameStart, false);
  gameLoop();
}

function gameStart() {
  gameStarted = true;
  canvas.removeEventListener('click', gameStart, false);
}

//The main function of the game, it calls all the other functions needed to make the game run
function gameLoop() {
  clearCanvas();
  drawStarfield()
  if (alive && gameStarted && lives > 0) {
   hitTest();
    shipCollision();
    moveLaser();
    moveEnemies();
    drawEnemies();
    drawShip();
    drawLaser();
  }
  scoreTotal();
  game = setTimeout(gameLoop, 1000 / 30);
}

//Checks to see which key has been pressed and either to move the ship or fire a laser
function keyDown(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) rightKey = true;
  else if (e.keyCode == 37) leftKey = true;
  if (e.keyCode == 38) upKey = true;
  else if (e.keyCode == 40) downKey = true;
  if (e.keyCode == 88 && lasers.length <= laserTotal) lasers.push([ship_x + 25, ship_y - 20, 4, 20]);
}

//Checks to see if a pressed key has been released and stops the ships movement if it has
function keyUp(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) rightKey = false;
  else if (e.keyCode == 37) leftKey = false;
  if (e.keyCode == 38) upKey = false;
  else if (e.keyCode == 40) downKey = false;
}

window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
function doKeyDown(e){

            //====================
            //  THE W KEY
            //====================
            if (e.keyCode == 87) {
                clearCanvas();
                y = y - 10;
                canvas_context.fillRect(x, y, 50, 30);
            }

            //====================
            //  THE S KEY
            //====================
            if (e.keyCode == 83) {
                clearCanvas();
                y = y + 10;
                canvas_context.fillRect(x, y, 50, 30);
            }

            //====================
            //  THE A KEY
            //====================
            if (e.keyCode == 65) {
                clearCanvas();
                x = x - 10;
                canvas_context.fillRect(x, y, 50, 30);
            }

            //====================
            //  THE D KEY
            //====================
            if (e.keyCode == 68) {
                clearCanvas();
                x = x + 10;
                canvas_context.fillRect(x, y, 50, 30);
            }

        }

        function clearCanvas() {
            canvas.width = canvas.width;
        }
```

The full explanation and code examples can be found [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/JS/html5_canvas_keyboard_keys.html) and a demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/nGMmD/)

Comment: Thank you very much... but its not working on my end, maybe Im doing something wrong, Im new to html5 gaming, What about adding control buttons to the screen to move the object that maps back to the keyboard keys?

Comment: sorry for the title of the question, this was a question i was about to ask yesterday but didn't remember to change the title